# Is it possible to use Windows Environment Variables in a putty logfile filename?

Tags: putty

Is it possible to include a Windows environment variable in a putty logfile filename? I  tried using "putty - %USERNAME%.log" as my logfile, but the output file literally contains "%USERNAME%" instead of the variable contents. This suggests that it's either not possible, or putty may have an alternate escape character for environment variables. I'm hoping it's the latter...

Comment: You mean in PuTTY GUI configuration? + What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, as configured in the GUI configuration. I’d like to include the current username in the log file name.

Comment: We know that. But why do you need to use variable for that? What's the point? Explain us.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if putty resolved env vars, we could set up a shared configuration for a team that could be distributed easily as a .reg export file. E.g. using `%USERPROFILE%` instead of hardcoded user ids can allow all the paths in the GUI to be standardized, relative to the user's home directory. Some of the paths I see are:  log location, X authority file, ssh key file etc.

Answer (score 3):

It rarely happens, but sometimes a Windows profile will "shift", moving from yourusername to yourusername.000.  Since I administer a thousand systems in a cloud center, I now have about a 1000 systems in PuTTY pointing to the old profile location for logging.  Using %USERPROFILE% environment variable would make the transition seamless.  As it is, the only solution I can see now is to export the PuTTY registry key, and search and replace the user name string with the new one.  Not difficult to do, but using the Windows environment value would be helpful.